# Insertar datos en comboBox

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Tengo el siguiente codigo,el resultado del cursor me devuelve los datos correcto, el problema que el comboBox no los muestra, es correcta la forma de llenarlo?

```
print([str(x[0]) for x in cursorUsuario])
```

> ['1', '4', '5', '6', '9']

```
self.dlg.comboLote.addItems([str(x[0]) for x in cursorUsuario])
```

Funcion donde lleno el comboBox

```
 def obtenerUsuario(self,doc):


        with open(doc, 'r') as searchfile:

                for line in searchfile:
                    if "url=https://test/ows/wfs" in line:
                        nombreConexion = line.split('\\')[1]
                        nombreUsuario = nombreConexion+"\\username"
                        passwordUsuario = nombreConexion+"\\password"

                        for linea in searchfile:
                            if nombreUsuario in linea:
                               usuario = linea.split("=")[1]
                               usuarioSiena = usuario.rstrip()

                sqlLote = ("select lot.idLote from [inf].[Lote] lot \
                                  inner join [dbo].[Usuario] u on lot.idUsuario = u.idUsuario \
                                  where u.userName = '%s'") % \
                                    (usuario)

                self.dlg.comboLote.clear()

                cursorUsuario = connUsuario.execute(sqlLote)

                print([str(x[0]) for x in cursorUsuario])

                self.dlg.comboLote.addItems([str(x[0]) for x in cursorUsuario])
```

Llamo a la funcion:

```
def run(self):

    self.dlg.comboLote.clear()


    self.obtenerUsuario("C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\QGIS\QGIS3.ini")
```

Comment: el codigo que muestra es correcto por lo que me hace sospechar que el error esta en otro lado, asi que si desea ayuda debe proveer un [mcve]

Comment: @eyllanesc incorpore un ejemplo mas completo

Comment: sin un [mcve] es muy poco probable que reciba ayuda, ya deberias a aprender a mejorar el formato de tus preguntas :)

Comment: El cursor (`cursorUsuario`) actúa como un iterador, cuando haces `print([str(x[0]) for x in cursorUsuario])` lo "consumes" y al volver a iterar sobre él con `self.dlg.comboLote.addItems([str(x[0]) for x in cursorUsuario])` no retorna nada, eliminando el `print` todo debe ir bien. Por cierto no necesitas una lista, basta con `self.dlg.comboLote.addItems(str(x[0]) for x in cursorUsuario)`.

Comment: Podrias agregarlo como solucion,funciono perfectamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si el adaptador como cabe esperar sigue las especificaciones de [PEP 249 -- Python Database API Specification](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/), `Cursor` debe implementar el conocido como *protocolo iterador*, lo que significa que retorna las filas de la consulta una a una hasta que se agotan, en cada iteración nos genera y retorna una nueva tupla con el contenido de la fila siguiente hasta que no queda ninguna, momento en el que genera un error `StopIteration`.

Esto tiene un razonamiento muy lógico, los iteradores/generadores son en esencia perezosos, no generan nada antes de que se les pida. En teoría, una buena implementación de un adaptador de base de datos debería obtener filas en lotes desde el servidor, no obtener toda la consulta de golpe con el consiguiente consumo de memoria al tener que mantener almacenado el conjunto completo de resultados simultáneamente.

Esto sería lo ideal, pero lo cierto es que depende del adaptador y de la base de datos, hay casos en los que la consulta se almacena al completo en el cliente (ya sea usando contenedores de Python o de C), en los que se almacena en el servidor... Esto no nos importa en realidad para lo que nos concierne, lo que hay que tener claro es que cuando se itera sobre un cursor ya sea mediante un `for in`, `fethone`, `fetchall` o cualquier otro método que implique iterar sobre el mismo (p.e `list(cursor)`) este se va "consumiendo".

Tu problema se debe en realidad al "inocente" `print` seguramente con fines de depuración:

```
print([str(x[0]) for x in cursorUsuario])
```

donde iteras sobre el cursor al completo para generar una lista que imprimes y dejas a merced del recolector de basura. Cuando vuelves a iterar en:

```
self.dlg.comboLote.addItems([str(x[0]) for x in cursorUsuario])
```

el cursor no tiene nada que retornar porque fue consumido en el anterior `for`. Podemos emularlo con:

```
>>> cursor = iter((("a", ), ("b", ), ("c", ), ("d", )))
>>> print([row[0] for row in cursor])
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

>>> [row[0] for row in cursor] # Genera una lista vacía
[]
```

Si eliminas ese `print` todo irá bien, ten en cuenta que `QComboBox.addItems` acepta cualquier iterable mientras que este contenga cadenas, por lo que puedes hacer simplemente:

```
 self.dlg.comboLote.addItems(str(x[0]) for x in cursorUsuario)
```

Si necesitaras realmente una lista, itera sobre el cursor una sola vez y asigna la lista a una variable, por ejemplo:

```
ls = [row[0] for row in cursorUsuario]
print(ls)
self.dlg.comboLote.addItems(ls)
```

---

Como apunte aparte, no deberías usar la barra diagonal inversa  en las rutas sin escapar. La razón es que `\` se usa para determinar secuencias de escape, por lo que en "C:\fichero\registro" `\r` es tomado como un retorno de carro... Usa la barra inclinada `/` o puedes normalizarla con [`os.path.normpath("C:\...")`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath).